# Decode not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't seem to figure out why this won't work - can someone please help? This is part of a larger query, so I don't want to have to update the one that already exists - just wanna add to it -

```
SELECT INNERPART.*,
       SUBSTR(status_remday, 1,1)   AS COMPLETE,

**--this line shows if it is completed or not**

      DECODE(SUBSTR(status_remday, 1,1),'Y','Complete','N','Incomplete', null)     AS qualCompleted,

 **--need this to show if the curriculum is complete or not, in it's own row. will eventually have about 10 or more qual_ids**

     decode(INNERPART.qualID,'ENG_CURR_SAFETY CERT', qualCompleted) as SAFETY
FROM (Innerpart)
```

Comment: . . No, no one can help.  You have provided code and said that it doesn't work.  But, you have not described how it is failing.  Nor have you provided sample data and desired results, showing what you want the code to accomplish.

Comment: So, you define `qualCompleted` in the `SELECT` clause, and then later you want to refer to it by name in the same `SELECT`? That doesn't work in SQL (certainly not in Oracle SQL). If you don't want another layer of outer queries, your only option is to **repeat** the `DECODE` function call, nested within the outer `DECODE`, when you define `SAFETY`.

Comment: To follow up on Gordon's comment, I'd highly recommend (or better said, insist) that you read the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rule. Not only it will help you ask a better question, but furthermore help us provide a better answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the SQL syntax (the Oracle dialect, anyway) doesn't allow you to define an alias in a `SELECT` clause and then reference the same alias in the same `SELECT` clause (even if it's later in the clause).

You define `qualCompleted` as a `DECODE`, and then you reference `qualCompleted` in the second `DECODE`. That won't work.

If you don't want to define `qualCompleted` at one level and then wrap everything within an outer `SELECT` where you can reference that name, your other option is to use the first `DECODE`, as is (not by alias) in the second `DECODE`.

This:

```
decode(INNERPART.qualID,'ENG_CURR_SAFETY CERT', qualCompleted) as SAFETY
```

should instead be written as

```
decode(INNERPART.qualID,'ENG_CURR_SAFETY CERT', 
       DECODE(SUBSTR(status_remday, 1,1),'Y','Complete','N','Incomplete', null) ) 
    as SAFETY
```

One more thing: by default, `DECODE` returns `null` if the first parameter is not matched in `DECODE`. So you don't actually need to give the last parameter (`null`) in your definition of `qualCompleted`.

**EDIT**: here is what the Oracle documentation says about column aliases.

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2080424

> **c_alias** Specify an alias for the column expression. Oracle Database will use this alias in the column heading of the result set.
>   The AS keyword is optional. The alias effectively renames the select
>   list item for the duration of the query. **The alias can be used in
>   the order_by_clause but not other clauses in the query.**

This means a few things. An alias like the `qualCompleted` you created **cannot** be used in the same query in the `WHERE` clause, `GROUP BY`, etc. - and not even in the `SELECT` clause where it was created. It can ONLY be used in the `ORDER BY` clause of the same query. Any other use must be in a surrounding, "outer" query. It also does mean, though, that you **can** use it in `ORDER BY`, if needed.

In your case, if you ONLY created `qualCompleted` so that you can reference it in another `DECODE`, and had no other use for it, then you don't even need to define it at all (since it doesn't help anyway); just define `SAFETY` directly as a nested call to `DECODE`.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was because I couldn't define the decode when it was already used, but I couldn't find a definite answer anywhere. Again thanks so much!

Comment: @Ginny - OK, I will add a link to the Documentation where this is stated explicitly.